# *ngFor iterate nested array of JSON

Tags: angular, ngfor

Hi I have  JSON data in below format. I want to render it in HTML page using angular.

```
questionarie = [{
   qText : " Issue Type",
   options : ["Functional Issue" , "Performance Issue" , "Crash Issue" , "Diagnostic Issue"],
   questionId : "1001",
   "parentId" : "",
   childs : [{
      qText : " Issue Type",
      options : ["Functional Issue" , "Performance Issue" , "Crash Issue" , "Diagnostic Issue"],
      questionId : "1001_1",
      "parentId" : "1001",
      childs : []
   }]
}];
```

I tried all below option.

```html
   <ul>
        <li *ngFor=" let item of questionnaries; let ind = index">{{item.qText}} 
            <ul>
                <li *ngFor=" let option of item.options; let optionIdx = index ">{{option}} {{ind2}} 
                  <ul ng-if="post?.capabilities?.item.childs[optionIdx]?.length > 0 ; let child = item.childs[optionIdx]; ">
                    <li >{{child.qText}}</li>
                  </ul>
               </li>
            </ul>
```

I am getting below error in browser console:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property qText of undefined

Comment: Your variable name is `questionarie` but you are accessing `questionaries` in your html

Answer (score 1):

ng-if is AngularJs, Angular uses *ngIf

You are iterating questionnaries but your array is called questionarie

Have you tried using

```
item.childs[optionIdx].qText
```

Rather than trying to let a view variable.

What is post?

Is this what you are looking for https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n5abdx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 1):

Your variable name is `questionarie` but you are accessing `questionaries` in your html

Comment: I tried item.childs[optionIdx].qText  and   let child = {tem.childs[optionIdx]}  then using {{ child.qText}} .  I have corrected json object name questionarie this not the problem. problem is in nested  <li >{{child.qText}}</li>   if I use only <li >{{child}}</li> html UI shows [object object] it means object is there but it is not typedcased to json equivalent.